# Getting properties by name in generic class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a generic react functional component in typescript that has a hierarchical nature.
The basic structure of the data I want to use is:

```
interface Data {
  id: number;
  children: T[];
}
```

and I want to set the props for my controls to look like:

```
interface Props<T> {
  item: T;
  key: keyof T;
  children: keyof T;
}
```

In the class I want to be able to use the props to access the items in the Data interface.

```
const childs = props.item[props.children];
```

but when I do this I cannot figure out a way to safely ensure that childs is an T[].
or use

```
prop.item[props.id]
```

as the 'key' to my elements.
C# developer just getting my feet wet in typescript, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:  Here's is my scenerio
I have this data structure

```
 interface AccountTotal {
  accountId: number;
  name: string;
  subaccounts: AccountTotal[];
}
```

and in my app.tsx I render a component

```
    <TreeGrid<AccountTotal>
      columns={columns}
      id='accountId'
      rootNode={accountTotal}
      children='subaccounts'
    />
```

the props in my component:

```
export interface TreeGridProps<T> {
  rootNode: T;
  children: keyof T;
  id: keyof T;
  indent?: number;
}
```

I am trying to use the 'keyof T' properties to get the values of rootNode.
In c# I would use reflection, but it seems like this may not work here.  My work around is to pass a function instead of the 'keyof T' properties.  Is that a valid way to pass props like this in react?

Comment: Can you make an example that links this together? I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you want here. Something like https://tsplay.dev/lWY0Qm. Also, you are going to have a hard time typing `children: keyof T`. I'm fairly sure React will always widen any `string` based children into a `string`.

Comment: `props.children` is a special prop in React.  https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx  Are you trying to access the element's children, or does this need a different name?  I can definitely help you but I am still trying to wrap my head around what you are trying to do.